# Предупреждение в консоли: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть такой код:

```
$('.hover-modal').hover(function(){
        $('.popup_custom').show()
            })
    $('.close_button').click(function(){
        $('.popup_custom').hide()
    })
        if(device.mobile() || device.ipad() || device.android())
            {
            $("#ytplayer").append("<img src=\"images/preloader_Youtube.gif\" id=\"apYou\">");
            $('.hover-modal').remove();
            $(".anticlicker").css('bottom','65%');
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('#apYou').hide();
            $("#ytplayer").append("<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/FrgyUDAnDQY?mute=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=1&amp;disablekb=0&amp;loop=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;playlist=FrgyUDAnDQY\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"\"></iframe>");
        },2000) 
        }
        else {
          $("body").append("<script src=\"js/youtubeUP.js\"><\/script>");
        }
```

Из-за этого кода в консоли появляется предупреждение: *Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.*

Из-за строки: `$("body").append("<script src=\"js/youtubeUP.js\"><\/script>");`

В чем может быть проблема, почему появляется предупреждение?

Comment: предупреждение появляется не из-за этой строки. Ты можешь проверить это, закомментировав содержимое `js/youtubeUP.js`

Comment: Закомментировал, предупреждение пропало.

Comment: очевидно проблема не в коде, предоставленном в вопросе, а в другом месте.